# How to find the .app file to submit application to AppStore?

Tags: ios, app-store, .app

I am attempting to submit an application to the AppStore but I am running into some trouble. When I build the application am unable to find the `.app` file.

In xCode4, I expand the Products folder and `myapp.app` file is red and right clicking on it doesn't allow me to select `Show in Finder`.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose "Build and Archive" to submit to the App Store. After the app finishes building, the Organizer should popup and allow you to submit/share or validate the app. Obviously, you want the Submit option.